# How to enable location settings for the app when app is not on the list of location services?

Tags: ios

[image]

The screen above describes situation. Any idea how to turn it on? I have ios 10.

The app I mean is **hostelbookers**. It was not happening while ios 9.

Location services for Safari are enabled:

[image]

And there is no my **hostelbookers** app on the list of location services. They are sorted alpha betically.

[image]

Comment: Try to enable location services for safari and the try again.

Comment: It doesnt work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried by opening http://www.hostelbookers.com in a browser. Same pop up shows up. I guess the website is not coded properly. They just made that button but its not probably working. Best alternative is search by entering city name.

Thanks